# Unable to access session variables from other scripts in php

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I have a login page which upon successfully validating email and password against the values of the database creates 3 session variables. The problem is that I'm unable to access these 3 session variables from other scripts even though session_start() is called before trying to access the variables from other scripts. On the login page too session__start() is called in the beginning and I'm able to print these 3 session variables on the same login page upon page refresh too.

My php version is 7.4 and the server is apache. I'm on a windows machine.

Comment: Show C:\xampp\htdocs\incBooks\2.php on line 3

Comment: @WiatroBosy i added the var_dump($_SESSION); in the login page and the result is "array(5) { ["LoginSenderToken"]=> string(97) "$argon2id$v=19$m=65536,t=4,p=1$Ty9HQlR6aFBXZ2xxTWVLOQ$R1zUlj5wbmkgZpgH8pj5JtqHSz/TgEcNc5NNHmGQoLA" ["randID1"]=> int(461) ["isLicenseExpired"]=> int(1) ["isEmail"]=> string(12) "eb@gmail.com" ["isUserID"]=> int(10) } ";

Comment: @WiatroBosy var_dumpt($_SESSION); on the script2 outputs "array(0) { }"

Comment: var_dump(session_start());  and this what show ?

Comment: C:\xampp\htdocs\incBooks\2.php on line 3 this is the same script2 file.

Comment: var_dump(session_start()); shows Notice: session_start(): A session had already been started - ignoring in C:\xampp\htdocs\incBooks\login.php on line 9

Comment: hym ? 2.php LINE 3 is "$LoginSenderPASS = @filter_var($_POST['password'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);" ther is no used $_SESSION

Comment: "A session had already been started " - this means that you have already started sessions somewhere.

Comment: @WiatroBosy why store the password in session on line 3? that's not required for my project.

Comment: session already started message is showing up because i have already started session above it. but that's only a notice there is no problem in creating and storing session variables.

Comment: No.  Error is on line 3  bat line 3 no use SESSION. You entered the wrong code or the wrong error code

Answer (score 0):

This is your code but simplified. Run, enter your email and password, click "login". Refresh the page a few times with F5

```
<?php
    session_start(); 
    var_dump($_SESSION);
    $LoginSenderEMAIL = @filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $LoginSenderPASS = @filter_var($_POST['password'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    




    if(isset($_SESSION['stest']) )
    {
        echo '<br/><b style="color:red;"> Session is OK.</b>';
    }
    else if(isset($LoginSenderEMAIL) && !empty($LoginSenderEMAIL) && isset($LoginSenderPASS) && !empty($LoginSenderPASS))
    {

        echo '<br/><b style="color:red;"> Form send. Session is OK</b>';
        $_SESSION['stest'] = 'testsesion';
    }
    else{ ?>

<form method="post">
    <table style="padding-left: 50px; padding-right: 50px;">
        <tr>
            <td class="rightAlign fontSize22">
                <label for="email"> Email: </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="fontSize22">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="rightAlign fontSize22">
                <label for="password">Password: </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="fontSize22">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="forgotPassword.php"><input type="button" value="Forgot Password?" class="fontSize22" style="background-color: #FF4F5A; border: none; color: white;"></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Login" class="fontSize22" style="width:100%; background-color: #FF4F5A; border: none; color: white;">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: the result is "Form send. Session is OK".

Comment: You see session data ? stest' => string 'testsesion'

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. I noticed that the login page was opened through localhost in the url while the script2 trying to access the session variables was being opened up through 127.0.0.1. Sessions in php are unique to the domain, so localhost and 127.0.0.1 are treated differently.